# What is the fastest way of selecting an photoshop object (layer)?

Tags: selection, photoshop, layer

When you have some simple layers in a .ps file you can use Ctrl + Click to select one of them.

What about when there are lots of imbbricated groups and you need to grab a layer that is on the lowest level on the groups hierarchy ?

Thx!

Comment: Can't be done. Just open the Group. Also, off-topic I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just use the move tool and select auto select from the toolbar. You can choose to select groups or layers.

Answer (score 1):

You can also right-click on the canvas over the object you want to select; a list with the layers that are under the cursor will pop up and you can click on the layer name (that's why it's always good to name the layers)